# What is the origin of “I calls ’em like I sees ’em”?

Tags: etymology, expressions, idioms, dialects

This expression seems to be pretty widespread, for example being in [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/call_it_as_one_sees_it#English) and [Futurama](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzHBKANVInY). Does anyone know what the origin is? Also, what kind of dialect might *I calls* or *I sees* be?

Comment: Note that "I call them like I see them" is plain old umpirese, and unremarkable by itself.  "Dressing it up" with dialect it likewise not all that remarkable, so it's not clear that you can reasonably expect to find an "origin" of the sentence.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure of the origin of the story, but the phrase comes from a story about an argument between three umpires. The first umpire says, "I calls 'em like I sees 'em." The second one says, "I calls 'em like they was." And the third one says, "They ain't nothin' till I calls 'em."

There are multiple interpretations of the story, and if you google it, you will find many mentions of it (so no official source). It seems to be a story about objectivity or perhaps perspective.

When it stands alone, it's a blustery statement about confidence in one's own view of the situation.

Comment: I would take your story to be a philosophical lesson constructed from an already-familiar saying.

Comment: I found a reference [here](https://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/three_umpires). First reference seems to be by a professor named Harvey Cantril. 
_August 1957, The American Journal of Psychiatry, “Perception and Interpersonal Relations” by Harvey Cantril, pg. 126_

Answer (score 2):

I believe it’s an [Umpire (baseball)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umpire_%28baseball%29) reference; the plate umpire has the job of “calling” the legality of a pitch (ball or strike).

Obviously this job requires the umpire to “see” the ball crossing in (or out) of the strike zone.

Finally, *’em* is an elision of *them*.

Comment: [Please ‘never’ use   on ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722).

Answer (score 1):

This phrase seems to come entirely from baseball umpires. Also, the original wording of the expression is "I calls 'em **as** I see 'em".

The earliest instance I can find is **1912**:

> He calls 'em as he sees 'em, and he's pretty nearly right most of the time.
>   <sub>[The Times Dispatch](https://virginiachronicle.com/cgi-bin/virginia?a=d&d=TD19120720.1.7&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22calls+em%22+%22sees+em%22------)</sub>

Another early example is from **1917**:

> Rigler calls 'em as he sees 'em, but outside of that he is right.
>   <sub>[The Evening World](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030193/1917-10-10/ed-1/seq-16/#words=%22calls%2Bem%22%2B%22sees%2Bem%22)</sub>

Here's another one from **1937**:

> Umpire Helmore says “he calls ’em as he sees ’em with no appeal.”
>   <sub>[Sausalito News](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SN19370723.2.35&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522calls+em%252522+sees+em-------1)</sub>

And from **1944**:

> "I'm the umpire," said the umpire, pushing back his little blue cap. "I calls 'em as I sees 'em. And I sees this ball as high and a little close. Now play ball!"
>   <sub>[Casey Jones and locomotive no. 638: story - Issue 638](https://books.google.com/books?id=7yRCAQAAIAAJ&q=%22I+calls+em%22+%22I+sees%22&dq=%22I+calls+em%22+%22I+sees%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXzPfq2OXZAhWCo1kKHY0TD3E4PBDoAQhFMAc)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer comes from the great Casey Stengel when he charged home plate in a series game when he managed the Yankees.

Stengel's batter, with 2 out and having a full count, did not swing on pitch number 7.   The home plate umpire yelled "Strike 3!"   Casey was furious, as were most of the Yankee fans. He charged the umpire and got in his face, screaming as only Casey could do.  The umpire responded in a clearly Brooklyn accent of the period: "I calls 'em as I sees 'em."  It was loud enough for a NY sports reporter to hear the words and write them down.  Remember in those days before security, reporters, VIPs and such sat to the side of home plate or just a row or two up. The ump had to yell loud enough to drown out Casey.

[image: Stengel arguing with an umpire]

Comment: I think it safe to say that many users on EL&U are neither American, nor baseball fans. For example, I am one of those. :)  So forgive me if I ask when did all this take place? And do you have any references which back up your claim? Thanks.

Comment: According to my dictionary, he managed the Yankees 1949-1960. (An exact date would be better, but...)

Answer (score 0):

it seems like to me that I heard red skelton say that in one of his charactors say I calls em the way I sees,em   boy. that was funny then.

Comment: Man, you're OLD!

Comment: Do you have an approximate date of when this was (or—better yet—an exact citation)?

Comment: @Laurel - Look up *The Red Skelton Show* on IMDB.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks. The show ran from 1951-1971, so that at least puts an approximate date on it. (This answer would still be improved with an exact date...)

Comment: @Laurel - It's an ooolllddd baseball cliche, easily going back to the 1920s, and possibly the late 1800s.